# problemas al instalar un proyecto en vite

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, vite

Al hacer `npm run dev` en mi proyecto me salta el siguiente error:

> vite\hellow-react\node_modules\rollup\dist\native.js:64
>
> Error: Cannot find module @rollup/rollup-win32-x64-msvc. npm has a bug related to optional dependencies (https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/4828). Please try `npm i` again after removing both package-lock.json and node_modules directory.

Tengo la version **Node.js v20.9.0**

Ya borre e instale de nuevo los paquetes y borre el cache pero no funciona.

Comment: Probaste borrando el `package-lock.json` y re instalando todo?